# C++ Visual Studio "Disgusting Macro Hack" compilation issue

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, macros, compilation

I am trying to re-create the vector class for my own understanding. I came across an issue recently with Visual Studio 2013 while trying to compile this code. I am getting an error for **each 'vector'** keyword that states:

[image]

I do not know if this is a range error within my class definition or if this is something else.*I have not played with any settings.*

```
 #include "../../../std_lib_facilities.h"

    class vector{
        int sz;
        double* elem; //pointer to the first element (of type double)

    public:
        vector(int s) :sz(s), //constructor - allocates s doubles , :size(s) is a 'initilization list'
            elem(new double[s])
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < s; i++)
                elem[i] = 0; //initialize elements

        }

        int size() const
        {
            return sz;
        }

        //read
        double get(int n)
        {
            return elem[n];
        }

        //write
        void set(int n, double v)
        {
            elem[n] = v;
        }


        //Every class that owns a resource needs a destructor
        ~vector() //destructor
        {
            delete[] elem; // free memory
        }

    };


    int main(int argc)
    {
        vector v(5);
        for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++){
            v.set(i, i);
            cout << "v[" << i << "]==" << v.get(i) << '\n';
        }
        system("PAUSE");

    }
```

---

If you need any more information please don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: Is adding #undef vector can help?

Comment: Whats in the header file?

Comment: I recommend you call your vector something else (like `myvector`), or don't include the header where that macro is defined.  If you can't avoid that header and don't want to rename your class, try `#undef` as suggested already.  Microsoft shouldn't be using macros for something that is protected by a namespace.  That's real low.

Comment: @paddy - it was Bjarne Stroustrup that wrote that macro, not Microsoft.  You could get in trouble for calling Bjarne "low" around here.  Not Microsoft, that's very popular.

Comment: Well, I'm protected by the fact that Bjarne Stroustrup thought it was 'disgusting', which is worse than 'low'. =)  I'd be interested to know why the macro is required.

Comment: The context seems quite clear from the [link](http://www.stroustrup.com/Programming/std_lib_facilities.h) Serdalis posted -- this header is Bjarne's own and is used for tutorial purposes. He creates a class `Vector` that inherits from `vector` but redefines `operator[]` to do range checking. The `#define vector Vector` then means that the students will get a range-checked vector. It's a nasty hack, but that's fine because it's just to facilitate a pedagogical example, not production code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming [this](http://www.stroustrup.com/Programming/std_lib_facilities.h) is the `std_lib_facilities.h` you have included. That file contains a macro

```
// disgusting macro hack to get a range checked vector:
#define vector Vector
```

This causes all following occurrence of `vector` in your code to be replaced by `Vector`.  So when you declare your `class vector` it gets changed to `class Vector`, and since the header you have included already declares a template type named `Vector`, you probably get a redefined symbol error. In addition, in main when you declare `vector v(5);` it gets changed to `Vector v(5)`, and since the the original `Vector` class declared in `std_lib_facilities.h` requires a template argument, you get the error message posted in your question about a missing template argument.

To solve this you could either rename your class to something other than `vector`, you could `#undef vector` after you include `std_lib_facilities.h`, or you could not include that header at all and just `#include <iostream>` since the only part of the standard library you are using is `std::cout`.

Answer (score 1):

While searching online, I found your [header file](http://www.stroustrup.com/Programming/std_lib_facilities.h)... which contains the line:

```
// disgusting macro hack to get a range checked vector:
#define vector Vector
```

I don't know why you are using it, but this is the cause of your problem.

To use a vector all you need to do is `#include <vector>`

To add some clarification, the header file creates a vector class called `Vector` and then the `#define` makes sure that all initialisations of `vector` will actually refer to this `Vector` class.

Renaming your class will get rid of this issue for you.

As a side note, that header file is horrid, be careful when using it.

Comment: The point is they want to create their own vector for understanding.

Comment: @BobbyDigital They can do that if they want. But this is what is causing his issue.

Comment: So I noticed that header has `using namespace std;`, wouldn't that pollute `vector` in total anyway?

Comment: You have to wonder if Bjarne is all that happy about how his language turned out :)

Comment: @HansPassant, No `static if` (yet) vs. VLAs (sort of). Decisions, decisions.

Comment: @BobbyDigital yes it would hence the #define for vector --> Vector (which is what the OP is running into).