# Is it possible to use a scoped type as a macro name in C++?

Tags: c++, macros

I would like to define a macro to accomplish the following:

```
#define std::vector Vector
```

I can't do this because "`:`" seems to be not allowed in a macro name. The reason I want to do this is that I am trying to use Stroustrup's range-checked Vector (from std_lib_facilities.h in his book Programming Principles and Practice). He uses:

```
// disgusting macro hack to get a range checked vector:
#define vector Vector
```

<sub>(the comment is Stoustrup's)</sub>

The problem is that I would prefer not to have "`using namespace std;`" in the header file that declares `Vector`. Which means that I need to use `std::vector` in other header files, and then Stroustrup's "macro hack" does not work. I get errors related to "`std::Vector`", which does not exist.

So my question is: is it possible to use a fully qualified type name as a macro name so as to replace it with something like "`Vector`"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ Visual Studio "Disgusting Macro Hack" compilation issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19716729/c-visual-studio-disgusting-macro-hack-compilation-issue)

Comment: This is not really a duplicate: it is another problem involving the "disgusting macro hack" and a different "vector".

Comment: A macro replaces one token, not 3. `std :: vector` is 3 tokens, as you can see from the fact that you can insert whitespace between the tokens.

Answer (score 4):

Don't use the preprocessor. That's what alias templates are for:

```
template<typename T>
using vector_in_use = std::vector<T>;
```

You use `vector_in_use` throughout your code base, and it will compile your code with `std::vector`. Then, to switch you only need to replace one line:

```
using vector_in_use = Vector<T>;
```

Comment: Thank you @StoryTeller. But the idea of the original macro is to be able to range check vectors in code written using `vector`.

Comment: This works @StoryTeller: `template<typename T>
using vector = Vector<T>;` but this does not `template<typename T>
using std::vector = Vector<T>;` i get Compiler Error C2061 with Visual C++ 2015

Comment: @freeze you cannot redefine `std::vector`, end of story. If you feel you must, you should re-examine your problem; maybe ask about it in detail on SO.

Comment: thank you for your help. I don't really feel I must. This all started because of a compiler error caused by changing the order of header files. It turned out that the problem stemmed from the macro in the original std_lib_facilities.h file from the book. So then I decided to see if I could find a way to make it work as intended. I guess the answer is that this is an example of why macros can be problematic.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can include your Vector into the std namespace, and then in every file it is used, you put define and undef:

```
namespace std
{
#include "Vector.h"
}

#define vector Vector
//...
#undef vector
```

It really is disgusting, lol... But that'd do what you want to do.